# Is there any way to link a several Textbox to a list on Window Form App C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a window form app with arround 20 textboxes, named "TB1", "TB2",....
The problems is, if I have to work with 20 individual textbox, it might be really annoying.
Is there any way to create a list like: TB[], then assign TB1 to TB[0], TB2 to TB[1],...?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: If you're working with these controls in the sense of loading data into them, look at databinding instead

Comment: It's actually like: I have a NumericUpDown to fill-in the number of textboxes.
E.g: if the Numeric shown 3, then only 3 first textboxes are enabled, other shall be disabled.

Comment: Using the code from my answer, you can do something like `_tbList.ForEach(tb => tb.Enabled = int.Parse(tb.Name.Substring(2)) <= _nud.Value)` - it'll ditch the TB from the name and parse the remaining number then examine if it's less than or equal to the NUD value. If it is less than the tb is enabled, otherwise it is disabled. Putting that in a ValueChanged event for the NUD should mean you can scroll the NUD value and see the textboxes enable/disable in sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're already in a list; they have to be added to a ControlCollection in order to even show up on a form

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("TB"))
```

will, for example, give you them (it picks on all textboxes directly on the form, with a name that starts TB. If you have other textboxes also called TBx that you don't want in this, then pick in another property that identifies the ones you do want, or e.g. rename the controls you're interested in so you can pick them up by a pattern in the name)

You could put this in a class level list, in the constructor:

```
class YourForm: Form{

  private List<TextBox> _tbList;


  YourForm(){

    InitializeComponent();

    tbList = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("TB")).ToList();

  }

}
```

And then you could do things like clearing all of them:

```
_tbList.ForEach(tb => tb.Clear());
```

List is used to give access to ForEach; it's a List thing, not a LINQ thing - normal arrays don't have ForEach. If you use an array rather than a list you'd need to write eg `foreach(var tb in _tbArray) tb.Clear();` but it's the same overall effect

Note, if your textboxes are in panels or group boxes, they won't be in `this.Controls` they will be in `thePanel.Controls`

Note2, if the order matters then you can sort strings of TB1, TB2 .. TB9, TB10, ... correctly with:

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
  .Where(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("TB"))
  .OrderBy(tb => (tb.Name.Length, tb.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the controls collection. The trick is hooking them all up to one event handler:

```
private TextBox[] TB = new TextBox[19];

public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  for (int i  = 0 ; i < 20; i++)
  {
    TB[i].Name = "TB" + i.ToString();
    // Set Location, Visible & Text
    TB[i].Changed += TextBox_Changed;
  }
}

private void TextBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Name.Replace("TB", string.Empty));
    Console.Write(TB[i].Text + " has changed");
}
```